# JQuery mobile - Can I scale the content of a page only?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, scale, viewport

I am using JQuery mobile to make a mobile website and on one of my pages I want the user to be able to scale the content and not have it set rigid. So I want the user to be able to pinch to zoom to make the web page bigger and smaller.

To do this I have the following code:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=yes, target-densitydpi=device-dpi"/>
```

This works OK except I have a header in my page, so its like this:

```
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        //header content
    </div>
<div data-role="content">
     //Content
</div>
</div> <!--Page end-->
```

But with this setup the header also scales as the user zooms in and out on the page. Is there anyway to make sure the header doesn't scale and only the content within the data-role="content" div scales?

Comment: easy solution, load that page inside an iframe, or move it to it externally not via Ajax. As you need to change viewport's meta tag for that page only.

Comment: I've found that iFrames can be a bit of a mess on Safari on iOS so I was wondering if there was a solution available that doesn't require an iFrame?

Comment: Another solution is to move to that page with Ajax disabled as to load it and replace previous DOM where zoom is locked.